# Is there a way to see tweets from only people who follow on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I'm wondering if there any way to see a 'reverse feed' of sorts. I want to see the tweets of people that are following me. Is there a web app for that, or some way to do it on Twitter?

Comment: Interesting concept. Have you tried just adding them to a list as you get follow notifications ?

Comment: Just what I thought +1, the easiest solution

Comment: The hard part of that is initially populating the list if you already have a few hundred followers. It will take a number of hours. I'm playing with the API to see if that can be automated.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a [list](http://blog.twitter.com/2009/10/theres-list-for-that.html) and create a custom RSS with this app: [TwitterList2RSS](http://twiterlist2rss.appspot.com/)

Comment: Also, there may be tools that automatically create such list for you. Check out for example http://formulists.com

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API gives you a list of your followers and can also pull all tweets from a given user. Combining these, it wouldn't be hard to create something that does what you want.